# Smooth conditional expectation with nonsmooth "reverse"

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions

I am looking for a concrete example of the following: $(X,Y)$ are real-valued random variables such that:

- $E[Y|X]$ is smooth
- $E[X|Y]$ is discontinuous

Even better, I'd like to see an example where all densities exist: $p(x,y)$, $p(x|y)$, etc.

Comment: Take $(X,Y)$ with Gaussian density restricted to the region $0<y/x<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is uniformly distributed on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Let $X=\tan(T)$, $Y=\sin(2T)$, so that the parametric [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot%20%7Btan%28t%29%2C%20sin%282t%29%7D%20for%20-pi%2F2%20%3C%20t%20%3C%20pi%2F2) of $(X,Y)$ looks like:

[image]

Then $Y = 2X/(1+X^2)$, so $E[Y|X]$ is smooth. But

$$E[X|Y]=
\begin{cases}
1/Y \text{ if }Y \neq 0\\
\ \ 0 \ \ \text{ if } Y = 0
\end{cases}$$
which is discontinuous.

This comes from calculating $E[X|Y]$ is (the limit of) a weighted average of the two solutions for $y=2x/(1+x^2)$:
$$\left\{\frac{1-\sqrt{1+y^2}}y,\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}y\right\},$$
where the weights are the relative probabilities that $(\tan(T),\sin(2T))$ is in the range $((1-\sqrt{1+y^2})/y\pm\delta,y\pm\epsilon)$ or in the range $((1+\sqrt{1+y^2})/y\pm\delta,y\pm\epsilon)$. The second range of $T$'s is just $\pm\pi/2$ minus the first range, so the probabilities are equal, and the average is equally weighted, which yields the simple formula.

Comment: Can you explain your calculation for $E[X|Y]$? I did a quick calculation and I am getting a different result (which is continuous). (FWIW, my calculation of $E[Y|X]$ agrees with yours.)

Comment: I revised the answer to explain the calculation, but I expect I won't make any further comments.