# Regularity properties of conditional distributions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis

Let $(X,Y)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$ be a pair of random variables with joint density $p(x,y)$. I am interested in the regularity properties of the conditional densities $p(y|x)$ and $p(x|y)$ (in the sense of a regular conditional probability). For example, under what conditions on $p(x,y)$, $p(x)$, and $p(y)$ are the conditional densities differentiable? Continuous everywhere, continuous a.e., etc.?

This question is inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394376/smooth-conditional-expectation-with-nonsmooth-reverse/394379) I asked. The counterexamples suggested there all involve some type of discontinuity on the joint $p(x,y)$, and have not given me much intuition behind this.

I have done some digging but have not found any literature on this question, which seems quite natural. I would be more interested in general literature references on this problem than specific results, but any pointers or suggestions are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

This question has hardly anything to do with the [regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) or with your previous question (because in the counterexample in the [answer to that question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394379/36721) no joint density exists).

In your present case, the conditional density
$$p(x|y)=\frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)}$$
is defined only for $y$ with $p(y)\ne0$.
So, if $p(x,y)$ and $p(y)$ are both continuous on the set $S:=\{y\colon p(y)\ne0\}$, then $p(x|y)$ is continuous on its domain $\mathbb R\times S$; if $p(x,y)$ and $p(y)$ are both differentiable on the set $S$, then $p(x|y)$ is differentiable on its domain; etc.

Comment: I guess I am not familiar with the "only if" part of your claim: Clearly, if the joint density exists and $p(y)>0$, then the conditional density exists and has the claimed formula. Do you have a reference for the converse? (If you do not wish to invoke regular conditional probabilities, I am not even sure how to formulate this statement.)

Comment: @user19200 :  The existence of a joint density was assumed in your own post. In such a case, the display in my answer is the usual definition of the conditional density; see e.g. page 3 in these lecture notes by Pollard: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Courses/241.fall97/Condit.density.pdf Also, I do not have "only if" in my answer (I have "defined only for"), and there is no such thing as the converse of a definition.